# Can a card have lozenges?

Tags: cards

Desktop app. Filters on top. Lozenges in filters. Search results display in cards. Now, can these cards have lozenges? No right? Cause I need to show which one of the filters each particular card corresponds to...I think it's is familiar pattern if filter criteria in a card is just plain text. It can be separated by commas, or otherwise.

If anyone can think of a website that shows this type of pattern, please tell me. I thought of Behance. It does that. Sort of.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Can you please paint a few of the examples you're speaking about. It'll give this question durability for the future. It's a decent opener to a question.  Can you change what you're asking to focus on the utility relative to a specific form of interaction?  e.g., obviously, a card can have a lozenge, or not, and many other generalities.  The specifics of use case and application make the question durable.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand you right, but you want to display chips (i guess thats what you call "lozenges") within a card.

Just an example from material ui which provides the user with choice-chips within a card.

[image]

I don't see why it would be a problem to display the applied filters as chips within a card.